# Delete folders containing certain files and keep others

Tags: batch

I have a collection of folders which I want to delete. All of these folders contain a file named `index.html`.

For example, this folder should be removed because it contains a file `index.html`: `c:\folder2\folder3\index.html`

But under the same root folder there are folders which contain allowed files like: `c:\folder2\folder1\software.rar`

So I need a solution to find all `index.html` files and keep the parent folder as a variable and delete it afterwards.

I tested with this and it makes a nice list but deletion is not working:

`dir /ad /b /s %1 >list.txt for /f %%g in (list.txt) do if exist %%g\index.html rd /s /q %%g`

Comment: You're probably getting the error that  the directory isn't empty. if so then enter the directory, delete all files, exit the directory, then remove the directory. something like cd %%g del /y *.* cd ,, rd %%g

Comment: Add to your question: OS and OS tag.

Answer (score 1):

Window 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.1

Delete only directories that contain `index.html` **For testing clear your desktop. There should be no directory named `folder2` on your desktop. A directory named `folder2` is created on your desktop.**

```
pushd $HOME\Desktop;ni -itemtype directory "folder2\folder3", "folder2\folder1">$null;ni -itemtype file "folder2\folder3\index.html", "folder2\folder1\software.rar">$null;explorer .\folder2;cls 
Read-Host "    
Test files have been created on your desktop. See explorer.
Press enter key to continue"    
Get-ChildItem .\folder2\*\index.html | ForEach-Object { 
  remove-item $_.directoryname -recurse
} 
explorer .\folder2;cls 
Read-Host "    
Directories containing index.html have been deleted. See explorer.
Press enter key to delete all test files"
ri (".\folder2") -recurse
popd 
#
```

Comment: do you mind making global comments on this script, see your skills :d

Comment: Accept the answer and I will answer any questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

Verbose:

```
$root = 'c:\TopLevel'
Get-ChildItem -path $root -filter index.html -File -Recurse | Select -expand Directory | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

short Version:

```
$root = 'c:\TopLevel'
gci $root index.html -Recurse | select -expand directory | ri -Recurse
```